# The Euler's phi function for interval

Tags: discrete-mathematics, totient-function

I've read about Euler's phi function. I know that we use it to calculate the number of co-prime numbers with n that are smaller than n. So, I want to know can we somehow use this function, to calculate the number of co-prime numbers with n **in any interval**? For example, if I want to know the number of three-digit numbers, that are co-prime with 60. I will be glad if you can help me with this!

Answer (score 2):

Any $n$ consecutive numbers form a complete residue system modulo $n$. Hence within these numbers, there are exactly $\phi (n)$ numbers that are coprime to $n$.

In your case, the set of 3-digit numbers is actually $900$ consecutive numbers. Among every $60$ consecutive numbers, there are $\phi (60)$ numbers that are coprime to $60$.

Since $900$ is a multiple of $60$, there are exactly $\left(\dfrac {900}{60} \phi(60)\right)$ 3-digit numbers coprime to $60$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please explain the first paragraph in more detail?

Comment: A complete residue system modulo $n$ is a set of $n$ numbers with distinct remainders when divided by $n$. Coprimeness to $n$ is preserved in modulo $n$, since $\gcd(a,60) = \gcd (a + 60k, 60)$ for integer $k$. Therefore in any complete residue system, there are $\phi (n)$ numbers coprime to $n$, which is the same as the case for the first $n$ positive integers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!!!

Answer (score 1):

For multiples of $60$, it is easy: the number of natural numbers less than $60m$ that is coprime to $60$ is just $m\cdot\phi(60)$. That's because the pattern of coprimes and non-coprimes of 60 repeats with a period of 60.

In fact, it repeats with a period of 30 (30 is the result of multiplying all the *unique* primes in the factorisation of 60), so multiples of 30 are easy: the number of natural numbers less than $30n$ that is coprime to $60$ is just $n\cdot\frac{\phi(60)}{2}$. In fact, the same is true for *any interval of $30n$ consecutive integers*.

As the set of 3-digit numbers is an interval with $30\cdot30$ integers, we get that there are $30\cdot 8=240$ three-digit numbers that are coprime to 60.

When the period length doesn't go nicely into the length of the interval as discussed above, things get a bit more complicated. Your best bet is probably to find the closest whole multiple of the period length, then check each of the remaining numbers by hand. For instance, three-digit numbers whose first digit is 1 gives an interval of length 100. Use the above approach on the first 90 (up to and including 189), then check 190 up to 199 one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Also, can you tell me, how to prove that pattern of co-prime of n repeats with a period of n? Or is this some consequence of the Euler function or something like axiom?

Comment: Whatever factors $60$ and $x$ have in common, $60$ and $60+x$ have exactly the same factors in common (Euclid's lemma says as much, and the e.g. the Euclidean algorithm is fundamentally based on this statement). In particular, the two pairs are either both coprime or neither of them are. Comparing $x$ to $x+30$ is only a smidgen more nuanced, but you can draw the same conclusion.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!